# Error in connect Oracle 18c using org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating an application that uses SprintBoot configuration and trying to connect to the database which is Oracle 18c.
when, my application trying to boot up, it shows below messages and then return connection refuse error:

Error message:

> 2019-08-27T12:02:02.37+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 06:32:02.372 [NOINFO]
>   [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -
>   Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'TestDB'
>   2019-08-27T12:17:03.56+0530 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make TCP
>   connection to port 8080: connection refused

The configuration snippet that i have made is like:
Config.java

```
   @Primary
    @Bean(name = "testDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {



        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        try {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@testDB.uk.fid-intl.com:1701/testDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("testuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("test");
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dataSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "**ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused**" has nothing to do with the database connection, that's Tomcat. Seems that something else is already running on port 8080, so Tomcat is failing to start.

I'm assuming that you're on Linux, if that's the case, you can use the following to find out what's bound to port 8080.

```
fuser 8080/tcp
```

or

```
lsof -i tcp:8080
```

Comment: The process usually stuck post printling below log: